# Installing gmapping on raspbian stretch

Tags: navigation, raspberrypi, rosinstall, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im a trying to run gmapping on multiple turtlebot3's, but since i cannot be the master for more than one turtlebot I want to make them run it by themself. Every guide for installing ros on raspbian is for raspbian jessie. When I try to follow those guides i end up with:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-slam-gmapping
```

I have also tried follow the guide "Installing ROS Kinetic on the Raspberry Pi" but when i tried to use

```
rosinstall_generator
```

it returned nothing in the terminal, so I am unsure what to do.
On a side note I was wondering if what I am duing is a good idea, is the raspberry pi 3 able to run such a program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290792/installing-gmapping-on-raspbian-stretch/) by [Cs.mariager](https://answers.ros.org/users/34744/cs.mariager/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can try

```
rosinstall_generator slam_gmapping --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-slam_gmapping-wet.rosinstall
```

check http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=gmapping  to find the correct name of rep

---

Originally posted by [leehaijun](https://answers.ros.org/users/36586/leehaijun/) with karma: 16 on 2018-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hansenmaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/36512/hansenmaster/) on 2018-10-25**:
i tried the command but it said

bash: kinetic-slam_gmapping-wet.rosinstall: Permission denied

any suggestion?